# Where can I find a reference guide of all OLE calls that are supported for Excel

Tags: excel, automation, ole

My question sounds like something that should come up with a simple google search but, alas, it doesn't.

There are plenty of hits with examples of how to create a new workbook or worksheet and whatnot, but there doesn't seem to be a comprehensive reference guide that lists all supported calls (and, preferable, how to use them.)

In my case, I'm planning to use Ruby (I can already open the file etc), but that's about it.

I want to read in an existing file, go through all its worksheets and cell and check if a row matches a specific pattern, and then do something with that. Not overly complicated.

But, e.g., how do I even figure out how many worksheets are in a workbook? etc. etc.

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best source would likely be the MSDN library.

Is this what you were looking for?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846982.aspx

Amended: Correct link should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861528.aspx as stated by barrowc in comments.

Comment: Right idea but wrong link, perhaps? That link is for an OLE object embedded within Excel whereas the question is about Excel being treated as an OLE object. The full Excel object model is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861528.aspx but I don't know if 100% of that model is accesible via OLE

Comment: Thanks. Have amended the answer.

Comment: The second link was the most helpful, after selecting the 'Reference' link. Not the best reference in its class, but does the job if you're willing to go the extra mile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good reference is *Writing Excel Macros* by Steve Roman, O'Reilly books ISBN 1-56592-587-4

I have the first edition, 1999, but surprisingly little has changed. Despite the title, this book is not only about programming in VBA, but also covers the Excel object model, in some detail.